# Issue with Dash application display on mobile chrome browser

Tags: python, plotly-dash

This Dash web application is deployed on Render and it works well on desktop browser while it does not display on mobile chrome browser.

I tried Tor browser on mobile and it displayed but not in chrome. Your help is really appreciated.

App : https://kati-m6cb.onrender.com/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.